# rechercher en utilisant le jradioButtom

Tags: java

try{
Dt.setRowCount(0);
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){ Rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT `N_Lot`,`N_Ot`,`intitule`,`Ste`,`localite`,`Montant_Sonlgaz`,`mta`,`mts`,`bta`,`bts`,`pcabine`,`pacc`,`gc`,`branchement2`,`branchement4` FROM `affairesonlgaz` NATURAL JOIN `cont`" + "NATURAL JOIN `besoin` NATURAL JOIN `type_equip` WHERE N_Ot="+ jtxtOt.getText());
jtxtOt.setText("");
}
else { Rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT `N_Lot`,`N_Ot`,`intitule`,`Ste`,`localite`,`Montant_Sonlgaz`,`mta`,`mts`,`bta`,`bts`,`pcabine`,`pacc`,`gc`,`branchement2`,`branchement4` FROM `affairesonlgaz` NATURAL JOIN `cont` "+"NATURAL JOIN `besoin` NATURAL JOIN `type_equip`"+" WHERE N_Lot="+jtxtLot.getText());
jtxtLot.setText("");
}
Le Message Unkonw Column '' in 'Where Clausse'

Comment: Please provide readable question in english. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks
and 
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question

Answer (score 0):

You really should improve this readability it is really painful to help atm. And prefer using English on stackOverflow as the community is composed by international people or post on French forum like developpez and OpenClassroom.

As far as I can see in this code without code formatting, and with your error, it may comes from your SQL query. please check the syntax of your Query. Be sure that the columns  N_Ot and N_Lot exist. And use `'` around your  `jtxtOt.getText()` String so it appears that way in the SQL query :

```
WHERE N_Ot='search'
```